# Signal "sigcont" in Android debugger

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk

Recently I upgraded my Android studio to 2.2.1 version from 1.5.4. Everything is great and all, but I encountered a weird **new** thing (at least to me it was), when I started my app in debug mode - Some signal called `SIGCONT`:

[image]

What happened was, when I wanted to run the debug mode, it asked me to upgrade something related to C++, which I did, and now this thing appeared. I have no idea what this signal represents, nor do I care very much, but it annoys me because it stops the app randomly.

When I start the app, upon clicking `RESUME` in the debugger 3-4 times, the app becomes responsive - e.g. it executes. Then I interact with the app and right before hitting **my breakpoints** that I manually set, it stops again at `SIGCONT` for some reason. Clicking `RESUME` 2 times now, resumes the app and then it hits my breakpoint. Resume again -> hits another `SIGCONT` and then another breakpoint of mine.

#### My question:

What does this mean and why is this happening? Is there a way to turn this thing off?

**Maybe important sidenote: I added NDK as well in this project.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"as far as I know, NDK transforms some part of the code to C/C++"_. No, the NDK is used to build C/C++ code, typically into one or more shared object (.so) that you can load and use from your Java code.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I had that part wrong then, yeah. But still how would that affect our current problem at hand?

Comment: Have you tried switching to the bundled JDK? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667885/android-studio-slow-debug-sometimes-stuck-on-waiting-for-debugger-sigsegv/46667886#46667886