# Android Studio - Slow debug, sometimes stuck on "Waiting for debugger", SIGSEGV crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug

This may come out as too broad a question, but this issue(s) is driving me nuts and I'd appreciate some help:

It seems that with each new Android Studio version, debugging gets more and more impossible. I'm experiencing the following issues:

1. Very slow debugging overall. Stepping over is a drag.
2. A high precentage of failed debugger connection attempts, where the device is hanging on "Waiting for debugger".
3. SIGSEGV "crashes", where the debugger would halt on a SIGSEGV on a random place (ususally right after launch) but I'd be able to click the *play* button and continue debugging.
4. Debugger disconnections.

This happens both on real devices and emulators, with a wide range of setups and Android API levels.

My rig is quite powerful: Win 10, I7-4810MQ, 16g mem, SSD. Current AS version is 2.3.3.

Can anyone help me make some sense out of this mess?

Comment: I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088299/signal-sigcont-in-android-debugger) some time ago with the 3rd problem you mentioned here. Never got an answer :D

Comment: @Vucko did swicthing to the default JRE fix the issue for you?

Comment: I eventually learned to live with that shit, project was done shortly after and I could no longer reproduce it in my newer projects :) Thanks anyway dude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the culprit was me using JDK 8 (1.8.0_45). I guess the situation did indeed begin deteriorating with Android Studio 2.2, when Google [made the switch to OpenJDK](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/09/android-studio-2-2).

The fix was to simply let Android Studio use its own JRE, which is based on the OpenJDK project.

In ***File*** -> ***Project structure*** -> ***SDK location***, I had to tick ***Use embedded JDK***:
[image]

Now I have to deal with the actual bugs in my app, but this is a whole different story...